# How does the Rows.Err() of "database/sql" work?

Tags: go

The official documentation for this says(https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows.Err):

> Err returns the error, if any, that was encountered during iteration. Err may be called after an explicit or implicit Close.

This would mean that any error thrown during the `Scan()`, must be present when I call `Rows.Err()`. But this is not happening.

Here's my code:

```
for rows.Next() {
    t := someStruct{}

    // To simulate err, I have removed one of the field 
    // ie. requires 6, given 5
    err = rows.Scan(&t.Field1, &t.Field2, &t.Field3, &t.Field4, &t.Field5)
    if err != nil {
        // Error printed by debug-  
        // sql: expected 6 destination arguments in Scan, not 5
        log.Debug(err)
        rows.Close()
        break
    }

    templates = append(templates, &t)
}

err = rows.Err()
if err == nil { 
    // Execution does reach here!!
    print("i donot know what went wrong here")
}
```

Can anyone help me understand how Rows.Err() is expected to work? and what i am understanding wrong about it?

Comment: "during iteration" I assume is meant the work done in `rows.Next()`.

Comment: "any error thrown" errors in Go are not "thrown".

Answer (score 2):

Rows.Err returns the error for advancing to the next row or error.

Next, NextResultSet and Err work together to enable simple code for iterating through rows and handling errors.

Answer (score 2):

http://go-database-sql.org/errors.html

> The error from rows.Err() could be the result of a variety of errors in the rows.Next() loop. The loop might exit for some reason other than finishing the loop normally, so you always need to check whether the loop terminated normally or not. An abnormal termination automatically calls rows.Close(), although it’s harmless to call it multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Err provides a way for wrapping packages to check for query errors **without calling Scan**. Err returns the error, if any, that was encountered while running the query. If this error is not nil, this error will also be returned from Scan.

https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Row.Err